# Monitor Windows executable while it is loading

Tags: windows, monitoring, executable

Is there Windows software that will allow you to see what an executable is doing while it is loading up? For example, monitor if the executable is modifying the registry, updating the file system, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at Microsoft's [System Internals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).  In particular, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).